# Change element of another class in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm studying HTML, PHP, CSS, Javascript and MySQL and in a particular project I'm having a problem trying to change the property of a class using hover. Here is an example:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: blue;
  background-image: url("../images/background.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.rain {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.rain.back-row {
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 60px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

body.back-row-toggle .rain.back-row {
  display: block;
}

.drop {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  width: 15px;
  height: 120px;
  pointer-events: none;
  animation: drop 0.5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes drop {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0vh);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translateY(90vh);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(90vh);
  }
}

.stem {
  width: 1px;
  height: 60%;
  margin-left: 7px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25));
  animation: stem 0.5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes stem {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  65% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  75% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.splat {
  width: 15px;
  height: 10px;
  border-top: 2px dotted rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(0);
  animation: splat 0.5s linear infinite;
  display: none;
}

body.splat-toggle .splat {
  display: block;
}

@keyframes splat {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  90% {
    opacity: 0.5;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(1.5);
  }
}

.loginp {
  position: relative;
  top: 45%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 6.25%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.login,
.pwr {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
  height: 25px;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  transition: 1s;
}

label.ll,
label.lp {
  top: 23px;
  left: 5px;
  position: relative;
  color: #9eb2c8;
  z-index: 2;
  transition: 1s;
}

input.login:focus~label.ll {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Tela de Login</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body onload="makeItRain()" class="back-row-toggle splat-toggle">
  <div class="rain front-row"></div>
  <div class="rain back-row"></div>

  <div class="loginp">
    <label class="ll">Login</label>
    <input class="login" type="text" name="login" placeholder="" />
    <label class="lp">Senha</label>
    <input class="pwr" type="password" name="senha" placeholder="" />
    <div>

<script> 

var makeItRain = function() {

  $('.rain').empty();

  var increment = 0;
  var drops = "";
  var backDrops = "";

  while (increment < 100) {
    var randoHundo = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (98 - 1 + 1) + 1));

    var randoFiver = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (5 - 2 + 1) + 2));

    increment += randoFiver;

    drops += '<div class="drop" style="left: ' + increment + '%; bottom: ' + (randoFiver + randoFiver - 1 + 100) + '%; animation-delay: 0.' + randoHundo + 's; animation-duration: 0.5' + randoHundo + 's;"><div class="stem" style="animation-delay: 0.' + randoHundo + 's; animation-duration: 0.5' + randoHundo + 's;"></div><div class="splat" style="animation-delay: 0.' + randoHundo + 's; animation-duration: 0.5' + randoHundo + 's;"></div></div>';
    backDrops += '<div class="drop" style="right: ' + increment + '%; bottom: ' + (randoFiver + randoFiver - 1 + 100) + '%; animation-delay: 0.' + randoHundo + 's; animation-duration: 0.5' + randoHundo + 's;"><div class="stem" style="animation-delay: 0.' + randoHundo + 's; animation-duration: 0.5' + randoHundo + 's;"></div><div class="splat" style="animation-delay: 0.' + randoHundo + 's; animation-duration: 0.5' + randoHundo + 's;"></div></div>';
  }

  $('.rain.front-row').append(drops);
  $('.rain.back-row').append(backDrops);
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The function on CSS

`input.login:focus ~ label.ll {
  color: red;
}`

My goal is that when the user passes the mouse over the `<input class="login">` something to happen with `<label class="ll">` label but I can not make it happen, where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems:

1. You're using `:focus`, which activates when an input element is clicked on and currently active (i.e. it has a blinking cursor), but you're asking for "when the user passes the mouse over", which is `:hover`.
2. You're using the general sibling combinator (`~`) to match the element `label.ll`, but you can only use that function to match elements that follow after the first one. In your DOM, the `.ll` element comes before the `.login` element.

Moving your `:hover` state to a parent element might be a better idea:

```css
.login-wrapper:hover label {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="login-wrapper">
  <label for="login">Login</label> <input id="login" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked! But what if I want to use `:focus`? I just tried replacing `:hover` with ´:focus´ and it did not work = (

Comment: `:focus` works on `input` elements, so you can't use it on `div`. Since `input` elements cannot have children and CSS cannot affect previous siblings, you could only have it affect a sibling that came after (again, using the `~` selector).

Comment: I did! Thanks!!!!!